# How to find a wep key inside a pcap file with only 2 IV?

Tags: wifi, wep, key, ctf

I have a pcap file that contains 3 packets. I need to find a **WEP** key inside these packets. These packets contains only two IV. It's not a live attack so I can't try brute force.[image: I think this packet contains the key.]

Comment: Are the two IVs the same? If yes, got everything you need for an attack.

Comment: Also, what does brute force have to do with it being a live attack? No one would do a brute force on any WiFi authentication live. Get a handshake, crack the password offline.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser they have different IVs. You are right it doesn't have anything to do with a live attack, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to break WEP you need to catch 2 packets with the same key and reused [IVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector#WEP_IV). The number of packets in order to break the key depends on the length of the IV, but you usually need more than one thousand.

In your case probably your 3 packets do not share the same IVs. This means that you cannot break easily the key. Your only way will be brute forcing the key and for that, you do not need any live attack.

You can use [airdecap-ng](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-airdecap-ng/) for bruteforce the key.